# How to save a XML file created in C# using XDocument in Root Folder

Tags: c#

this is my code to create a XML file using XDocument class, but the file was save inside of Debug folder, what i really want is save inside of Project! Thanks

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("checkout",
                                       new XElement("currency","BRL"),
                                       new XElement("items",
                                       new XElement("item",
                                           new XElement("id", "0001"),
                                           new XElement("description", "caneca"),
                                           new XElement("amount","10.00"),
                                           new XElement("quantity","1"),
                                           new XElement("weight","50"))),
                                       new XElement("reference", "REF5678"),
                                       new XElement("sender",
                                       new XElement("name","Nathiel"),
                                       new XElement("email", "joanito@sandbox.pagseguro.com.br"),
                                       new XElement("phone",
                                       new XElement("areacode","51"),
                                       new XElement("number", "95453305"))),
                                       new XElement("shipping",
                                       new XElement("type","1"),
                                       new XElement("adress",
                                       new XElement("street","Rua da Insanidade"),
                                       new XElement("number","102"),
                                       new XElement("complement","CASA"),
                                       new XElement("district","centro"),
                                       new XElement("postalcode","54315310"),
                                       new XElement("city","Recife"),
                                       new XElement("state","PE"),
                                       new XElement("country","Brasil")))));
        doc.Save("document.xml");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to enter a path for the save file?

```
doc.Save("C:\Users\(name)\Documents\document.xml");
```

Or maybe promt user where to put file:

```
XDocument.Save(FolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath + "\\" + "document.xml")
```

Comment: the thing is, its a aspnet with Nancy, so i need to generate this xml inside of root Project folder,i tried to use FolderBrowserDialog but it cound't find the class!

Comment: Did you remember to add `using System.Windows.Forms;` for the file browser. This might help for the root folder: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getpathroot(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i found this `doc.Save(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "//..//..//docume.xml");` it Works,but i can't see in Visual studio Project tree,but its there,i will have any problem with that?

Comment: when I run `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` I get the path `"C:\Users\(name)\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\(project name)\(project name)\bin\Debug\"`, maybe check there for your file. The program is running from the debug folder once visual studio has compiled it, so naturally that will be its root folder.